# Codeigniter based website on Mochahost displaying blank pages

Tags: codeigniter, cpanel, web-hosting

Hi i'm a bit new at uploading a website to a webserver and i've encountered a problem.

my site is using codeigniter and my host is MochaHost.

First of all I already successfully uploaded the site i made it run twice,
but on my last upload of updated files the power went out and the upload stopped half-way through. And when the power was back I reuploaded the updated files.

Now, the problem is that when ever i try to open my site it only displays a blank page. I've tried to view specific page but it still displays a blank page. Here's the site: http://www.sph-mis.com/ .. displaying only blank pages

I read somewhere that the problem  might be the directory in were i put the files, and i put it on the public_html directory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciuDN.jpg

The 1st and 2nd try i did worked with the same directory but now its doesnt work.
now it just displayig blank sapce;

Can anyone help me with this?

**FIXED**

check the reply i made below

Comment: it is not a problem with machahost.. try to delete application,system and other codeginiter files.. and upload it again..

Comment: the http://www.sph-mis.com/ is the only domain u have at your server or you have others also

Comment: Ive already tried to delete it and re upload it multiple times but still no luck. Yes its the only server

Answer (score 0):

So really the question is how to I debug a blank page in CodeIgniter.  I don't know if there are some php errors waiting to be found behind that white screen of death but its your first step to figuring it out.  So here goes some ways to get some errors you can actually work with.

in your .htaccess file where index.php is located put this into it: (if none exists create it)

```
# display php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

if you get a 500 error your host may be using suPHP and you cant do it this way.

another thing to do is try this

for ci older then 2.x modify the error_reporting function in index.php to use E_ALL

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

for ci newer then 2.x [instead set ENVIRONMENT in index.php as](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/environments.html):

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

this sets the error_reporting to E_ALL.

You can also set in application/config/config.php

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;//or 1 for error messages only
```

then check for a log file in the application/logs/ directory (make sure its writable)

Also make sure your db settings are correct.  CI may suppress a database connection error.

Lets see if that gets you any further.

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir. I tried what you suggested but still no luck. But I already fixed it, what i did was got a clean copy of codeigniter and replace the application folder and added my assets folder to it and then uploaded it.. and it worked. Something must have been wrong within my old system folder.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it, what i did was got a clean copy of codeigniter and replace the application folder and added my assets folder to it and then uploaded it.. and it worked. Something must have been wrong within my old system folder.